# CodeIgniter ajax reloading page issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a page with ajax pagination on it, I am currently able to check if the session exists and process accordingly. However, I cannot seem to remove the menu or reload the page properly if the session has expired. Only the menu remains and the login page shows in the small area where the table was.

Controller code

```
public function index()
    {
        $conditions = array();
        $data = array();
        $totalRec = count($this->DocumentModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions));
        $config['target']      = '#list';
        $config['base_url']    = site_url('/AdminDocuments/Search');
        $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page']    = $this->get_per_page();
        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['links'] = $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();
        $data['datatable'] = $this->DocumentModel->admin_get_and_search(array('limit'=>$this->get_per_page()));
        $data['user'] = $this->AccountModel->get_person($this->get_person_id());
        $data['current_page'] = $this->ajax_pagination->getCurrPage();
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/header');
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/navigation');
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/title');
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/errors');
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/search');
        $this->load->view('admins/documents/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('layout/admins/common/footer'); 
    }

    public function search(){
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            if(!$this->logged_in()){
                $this->index();
            }else{
                $conditions = array();
                $page = $this->input->post('page');
                if(!$page){
                    $offset = 0;
                }else{
                    $offset = $page;
                }
                $keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');
                if(!empty($keywords)){
                    $conditions['search']['keywords'] = $keywords;
                }
                $totalRec = count($this->DocumentModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions));
                $config['target']      = '#list';
                $config['base_url']    = site_url('/AdminDocuments/Search');
                $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
                $config['per_page']    = $this->get_per_page();
                $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
                $conditions['start'] = $offset;
                $conditions['limit'] = $this->get_per_page();
                $data['links'] = $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();
                $data['datatable'] = $this->DocumentModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions);
                $data['current_page'] = $this->ajax_pagination->getCurrPage();
                $this->load->view('admins/documents/ajax_pagination', $data, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

My JS Code that is placed in the view

```
<script>

function searchFilter(page_num) {
    page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
    var keywords = $('#search').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url/AdminDocuments/Search/'+page_num,
        data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        success: function (html) {
            $('#list').html(html);
            $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}

function changeStatus(input){
    var id = input;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'url/AdminDocuments/ChangeStatus/',
        data:'id='+id,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
            searchFilter(0);
            $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}

function deleteDocument(input){
    var id = input;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'url/AdminDocuments/Delete/',
        data:'id='+id,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        success:function(result){
            searchFilter(0);
            $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you post your js code as well ?

Comment: Hey Yeah sure. My pagination code is loaded from the ajax pagination library and there is javascript there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am assuming `$('#list').html(html);` code loads the html in the dom. instead of directly sending the html from php you can send a json containing the html as well the login status. like this.

```
$data = [
  'login_status' => 1 // or 0,
  'html' => $html // full html your are sending now
];

echo json_encode($data);
```

then in ajax success.

```
function searchFilter(page_num) {
    page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
    var keywords = $('#search').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url/AdminDocuments/Search/'+page_num,
        data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.loading').show();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(response);

        if(data.login_status == 0)
        {
          window.location.href = 'redirect to login page';
        }

        if(data.login_status == 1)
        {
          $('#list').html(data.html);
        }
            $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
}
```

controller method :

```
public function search(){
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){

                $conditions = array();
                $page = $this->input->post('page');
                if(!$page){
                    $offset = 0;
                }else{
                    $offset = $page;
                }
                $keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');
                if(!empty($keywords)){
                    $conditions['search']['keywords'] = $keywords;
                }
                $totalRec = count($this->DocumentModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions));
                $config['target']      = '#list';
                $config['base_url']    = site_url('/AdminDocuments/Search');
                $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
                $config['per_page']    = $this->get_per_page();
                $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
                $conditions['start'] = $offset;
                $conditions['limit'] = $this->get_per_page();
                $data['links'] = $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();
                $data['datatable'] = $this->DocumentModel->admin_get_and_search($conditions);
                $data['current_page'] = $this->ajax_pagination->getCurrPage();
                $html = $this->load->view('admins/documents/ajax_pagination', $data, true);
    $res['html'] = $html;
    $res['login_status'] = ($this->logged_in()) ? '1' : '0';

       echo json_encode($res);

        }
```

Comment: $('#list').html(html); loads the html in the dom. I have tried redirect('/Login') but the problem is that it only reloads the list container. Will window.location reload the entire screen?

Comment: yup it will reload the entire screen

Comment: `redirect('/Login')` in php, it will only send the login whole login page in response to ajax but if u do it after the ajax response i.e in success `window.location` it will reload the entire page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. I have tried window.location.href but it still does the same thing. It reloads the container only for some reason.

Comment: did u do it in success block of ajax response ?

Comment: Sorry in the setting of $data. What is the full html i am sending?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147422/discussion-between-riaz-laskar-and-jianya).